# How to delete a daemonset and service in Kubernates

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes so pardon me if you find my question noob.

I have created a Daemonset called **testDaemon.yml** which is having a service in it called **testService**. Both were created but now I have made some minor changes and I need to re-create it.

I tried deleting the services and daemonset:

```
kubectl delete ds testDaemon
kubectl delete svc testService
```

but both of them is getting recreated everytime I delete them and I am getting an error that `services "testService" already exists`when I run kubectl create -f testDaemon.yml again.

What should I do to remove the DaemonSet completely or update the same with the new template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete it using 
`kubectl delete -f testDaemon.yml`

It will delete the statefulset and service both.